# Android: Enable Disable Context Menu Item

Tags: android, contextmenu

I want to enable and disable Context Menu, suppose in Context Menu Five Action is there and after selecting fifth action first action will disable and only enable when I select Fourth Action or doing some thing in other method of the application .

Suppose the code is:

```
public void onCreateContextMenu(ContextMenu menu, View v,
        ContextMenuInfo menuInfo) {
    super.onCreateContextMenu(menu, v, menuInfo);
    menu.setHeaderTitle("Option Menu");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "First Action");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Second Action");
     menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Third Action");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Fourth Action");
    menu.add(0, v.getId(), 0, "Fifth Action");
}
```

now when I select First Action then this Action will disable and only enable when I select Fourth Action or done some calculation in other method of this application. Please Suggest me...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an inherited method `removeItem(int id)` to remove an item from the context menu.